# Returning value with Task.Factory to Update the UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, task

This should be pretty easy , but i couldn't find a adequated term to search for... Well I'm new to C# and i'm trying to make a simple App to write the return of a webservice.

I came across the need to use a Thread... passing parameters to the thread is fairly easy , I couldn't find a way to return from the Threaded method and update my UI to show the result (well actually no the real result for now)

The event:

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        minhaSigla = Sigla.Text;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetQuoteAndUpdateText(minhaSigla));
        tb1.Text = "UIElement-TO-UPDATE";

    }
```

And then the Threaded method

```
    private string GetQuoteAndUpdateText(string sign)
    {
        string SoapEnvelope = "";
        SoapEnvelope = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
        SoapEnvelope += "<soap:Envelope ";
        SoapEnvelope += "xmlns:xsi = \"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" ";
        SoapEnvelope += "xmlns:xsd= \"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" ";
        SoapEnvelope += "xmlns:soap= \"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
        SoapEnvelope += "<soap:Body>";
        SoapEnvelope += "   <GetQuote xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\"> ";
        SoapEnvelope += "       <symbol>" + sign + "</symbol> ";
        SoapEnvelope += "   </GetQuote> ";
        SoapEnvelope += "</soap:Body>";
        SoapEnvelope += "</soap:Envelope>";

        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx");
        BasicHttpBinding basicbinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        basicbinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(3000000000);
        basicbinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(3000000000);

        stockbyname.StockQuoteSoapClient sbn = new stockbyname.StockQuoteSoapClient(basicbinding, endpoint);

        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        return sbn.GetQuote(SoapEnvelope);
    }
```

Also any information will be much appreciated, even comments about how awful my code is :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without getting into all the fun [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) stuff, you can use the [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321474.aspx) method of [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) to handle the returned information.

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    minhaSigla = Sigla.Text;
    var quoteGetterTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetQuoteAndUpdateText(minhaSigla));
    quoteGetterTask.ContinueWith(task => 
    {
        var theResultOfYourServiceCall = task.Result;
        //You'll need to use a dispatcher here to set the value of the text box (see below)
        tb1.Text = theResultOfYourServiceCall;     //"UIElement-TO-UPDATE";
    });
}
```

As I mention in the above code sample, depending on which UI technology you're using you'll need to use a dispatcher to avoid getting an illegal cross thread access exception.

WinForms example of the expression inside the `.ContinueWith` (using the [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) method of [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36cd312w.aspx))

```
task =>
{
    var theResultOfYourServiceCall = task.Result;
    tb1.Invoke(new Action(() => tb1.Text = theResultOfYourServiceCall));
}
```

WPF example of the expression inside the `.ContinueWith` (using WPF's [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx))

```
task =>
{
    var theResultOfYourServiceCall = task.Result;
    tb1.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                          new Action(() => tb1.Text = theResultOfYourServiceCall));
}
```

Silverlight/Windows Phone example of the expression inside the `.ContinueWith` (using Silverlight's [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615907%28v=vs.95%29.aspx))

```
task =>
{
    var theResultOfYourServiceCall = task.Result;
    tb1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => tb1.Text = theResultOfYourServiceCall);
}
```

Windows Store example of the expression inside the `.ContinueWith` (using [CoreDispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync.aspx))

```
task =>
{
    var theResultOfYourServiceCall = task.Result;
    tb1.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => tb1.Text = theResultOfYourServiceCall);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

More Commonly, you will need a task on the UI thread, since this lets you update your control.

```
Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetQuoteAndUpdateText(minhaSigla)).ContinueWith(s=>  tb1.Text = s, 
TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

ps : you can also use await & async in .net 4.5

Answer (score 1):

Other folks have mentioned `async`/`await`, but here's a simple example:

```
private async void TextBox_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    minhaSigla = Sigla.Text;
    string result = await GetQuoteAndUpdateTextAsync(minhaSigla);
    tb1.Text = "UIElement-TO-UPDATE";
}

private Task<string> GetQuoteAndUpdateTextAsync(string sign)
{
    string SoapEnvelope = "";
    SoapEnvelope = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
    SoapEnvelope += "<soap:Envelope ";
    SoapEnvelope += "xmlns:xsi = \"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" ";
    SoapEnvelope += "xmlns:xsd= \"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" ";
    SoapEnvelope += "xmlns:soap= \"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
    SoapEnvelope += "<soap:Body>";
    SoapEnvelope += "   <GetQuote xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\"> ";
    SoapEnvelope += "       <symbol>" + sign + "</symbol> ";
    SoapEnvelope += "   </GetQuote> ";
    SoapEnvelope += "</soap:Body>";
    SoapEnvelope += "</soap:Envelope>";

    EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx");
    BasicHttpBinding basicbinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    basicbinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(3000000000);
    basicbinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(3000000000);

    stockbyname.StockQuoteSoapClient sbn = new stockbyname.StockQuoteSoapClient(basicbinding, endpoint);

    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    return sbn.GetQuoteAsync(SoapEnvelope);
}
```

Note how similar it is to your existing methods. That's the power of `async`.